# Get keys of union of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to get all keys of type union type of objects `{ a: ...} | { b: ...}` ? One thing worth mention — this type is generated dynamically.

Spent a few hours but without any luck...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conditional types follow the *distributive law*.

Something along these lines (or at least a start)

```
type Keys<T> = T extends {[key: string]: any} ? keyof T : never

type Test = Keys<{a: string} | {b: number} | {c: object}>

//type Test = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVAfFAvFFUIA9gIA7AEwSgG8BtAa3gC4oFgAnAS2IHMBdJljtwC+UAPxR6IAPYAzHFCYBXMhBmcIpAFCbQkHBBZZY8ZJQCG-Npy4iAPlQBGlwTaj3KAY2fWhaIA)

Comment: Magnificent! Thank you!