# Use keys of an object as union-type

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I've got a object (let it be frozen so typescript may handle its keys better):

```js
const obj = Object.freeze({
    'hello': 64,
    'world': 20
}) as {[key: string]: number};
```

Now I have a function where the user can pick values by their keys:

```js
const pick = (keys: Array<string>): Array<number> => {
    const values = [];

    for (const key of keys) {

        // Check if object contains property-key
        if (!(key in obj)) {
            throw new Error(`There's no such key: ${key}`);
        }

        values.push(obj[key]);
    }

    return values;
};
```

That's looking good so far and works flawlessly during runtime where I check if the user passed any invalid keys. But how can I tell TS that only keys from `obj` can be used?

I could do `Array<'hello' | 'world'>` but I'd need to update it any time I add new properties to `obj` which is kinda annoying.

Related questions but they all seem to use types whereas I only have a object (which can be frozen if that helps):

1. [Make union type of objects from type keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338925/make-union-type-of-objects-from-type-keys) (He got a type, I'm with a object)
2. [get union type of object keys filtered by type of object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749772/get-union-type-of-object-keys-filtered-by-type-of-object-value) (Basically the same as 1. but he wants the `type` whereas I'm trying to build a type *out of* my object)
3. [Get keys of union of objects in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474456/get-keys-of-union-of-objects-in-typescript) (Looks good but he also got a type...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
const obj = Object.freeze({
    'hello': 64,
    'world': 20
});

const pick = (keys: Array<keyof typeof obj>) {...}
```

As you can see I have removed `as {[key: string]: number};` as it was widening the type, where you wanted to have it strict.

Next things is `Array<keyof typeof obj>` I declare here that I accept as argument only array of keys from type of `obj`.

`Array<keyof typeof obj>` evaluates dynamically into `("hello" | "world")[]`, fortunately as you wanted it will reflect every change in original `obj`